# General exercise, before meeting a vocal coach?

Tags: voice, learning, voice-training

I like to get some input. I am not sure where to ask beside SE. Apologize for quite a long post.

I am a male (26) who likes singing, but rarely sing. That is possible, I guess? I love it because I am amazed how singers can produce voice easy to listen to and I like music in general too, but rarely practice because of my study (previously) and job (currently). For next semester (3 months from now) I have decided I will be getting a lesson because I need to do some refreshing stuff beside working and will have enough time and money (not now) to spend. I am thinking it should be a good hobby just to sing and perform better.

Hence about the question, are there some exercise, or even habit, recommendations I can do on my own to improve my singing just a little BEFORE the lesson? And how often would it be for effective practice? Like 20-30 minutes every day? Should I not sing before/after those practice minutes? Or in general what do I do?

I have searched for other sources but I know improving singing differs between people, hence I am not sure which fits me, before my vocal teacher later hopefully guides me, so maybe for a little bit description: I had experience before in college, asked to sing in front of many people (luckily a duet) and practicing around 3 to 4 years ago, though I am 100% sure it was far from good and the practice was not that serious, only focusing on vocalization exercise. The only other general tips from the coach were "breath using stomach" and "sometimes screaming is better instead of holding back". I can hit or know the shakiness of my notes while singing. That coach thought my voice was good but only in some comfort (small) range still and can be improved. Vocal-wise I think mine is not that developed. I hope I could get some small input before my first focused lesson with coach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just sing - normally. I don't believe you're too busy to sing. In the car, walking, sitting round at home, in the bathroom, there are many times when you can sing.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by blowing raspberries with your lips to warm them up.

Singing scales up and down, starting in a comfortable range and moving it up, can help you warming up and especially warm up your range.

Here is a link to sing along if you're not sure how to sing a scale.